# Kotlin : get value of the clicked item list view (Fragment + Adapter)

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to get the clicked value from my list view from outside the ListView. When I click on my item, I want to fill a textView inside my fragment.

In the fragment, I have a searchView and the ListView.

this is my adapter :

```
class ListAdapterHoraire (context: Context, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<String>, private val arguments: Bundle?, private val forScol : Boolean) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list) {

    private val TAG = ListAdapterCustom::class.java.simpleName
    var nameArret: String = ""

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)

        val arret = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.arret)
        val receivedBundle = arguments    
        arret.setOnClickListener {
            val fragment = HorairePassage()
            fragment.arguments = receivedBundle
            nameArret = arret.text.toString()
            Log.i(TAG, "${arret.text} clicked")
            getArretCode(arret.text.toString(), fragment) //récupération du code arret + changement de fragment (en cascade)
        }

        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorWhite)
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayBackground)
        }



        return view
    }
```

Part of the fragment :

```
search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(newText: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                if(newText.length > 3){
                    loadingArretSearch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    getListeArrets(view, newText.trim(), resultArgument)
                    adapter = ListAdapterHoraire(view.context, R.layout.list_adapter, lignes, resultArgument, false)
                    listSearchView.adapter = adapter
                    adapter.filter.filter(newText.trim())
                    if(newText.trim() != ""){
                        listSearchView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }else{
                        listSearchView.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }else{
                    lignes.clear()
                    loadingArretSearch.visibility = View.GONE
                    listSearchView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                return false

            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a cases like this --> try to pass a callback into the adapter and the you can lunch any method from your activity and then you can do what you want from your activity .

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter(params , val itemClick: (Int) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    internal inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        ...
        itemView.setOnClickListener( {itemClick(layoutPosition)} )
    }
}

In your fragment or Activity 

val myAdapter = MyRecyclerViewAdapter(params) { position ->
    // do something
}
```

--> in your case

```
ListAdapterHoraire(view.context, R.layout.list_adapter, lignes, resultArgument, false){value->
  // do something
}  

class ListAdapterHoraire (context: Context, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<String>, private val arguments: Bundle?, private val forScol : Boolean,onItemClicked: (text: String) -> Unit) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list) {

         ...


         arret.setOnClickListener { onItemClicked(arret.text.toString()) }

         ...

        }
```

Comment: Can you please adapt this without recycler view ?

Comment: can you ckeck the exemple

Comment: adapter = ListAdapterHoraire(view.context, R.layout.list_adapter, lignes, resultArgument, false){ value -> Log.i(TAG, "clicked value $value")}

Comment: and your adapter

Comment: arret.setOnClickListener { onItemClicked(arret.text.toString()) }

Comment: do your arret.text.toString() has a value ? check please

Comment: My bad, wrong log displayed. Thanks ! What should I do if I need to send 2 values to the fragment ?

Comment: the same thing , you just need to pass the callback like the activity

Comment: if i do this : private val arguments: Bundle?, private val forScol : Boolean, private val onItemClicked: (text: String) -> Unit, private val infos: (text: String) -> Unit, the IDE ask me to pass an argument for onItemClicked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186554/discussion-between-b-mansouri-and-projet-sin).

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a function as parameter in the constructor, and call it when onClickListener is invoked:

```
class ListAdapterHoraire (context: Context, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<String>, private val arguments: Bundle?, private val forScol : Boolean,
 private val onItemClicked: (text: String) -> Unit) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list) {       
         ...


         arret.setOnClickListener { onItemClicked(arret.text.toString()) }

         ...

        }
```

So, in your fragment update the adapter instance

```
adapter = ListAdapterHoraire(view.context, R.layout.list_adapter, 
             lignes, resultArgument, false,
             { text -> Log.i("TAG", text) /** Do something here **/ })
 ...
```

Comment: I don't understand... And "onItemClicked" is not detected in my adapter